# How to create an instance of an inner class during construction of an outer class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
data class Outer(val x: Int = 1, val predicate: Predicate<Int> = Inner()) {
    private inner class Inner : Predicate<Int> {
        override fun test(t: Int): Boolean = x == t
    }
}
```

I get an error `Constructor of inner class Inner can be called only with receiver of containing class` where `Inner()` is called. Also if I do `this.Inner()` I get `'this' is not defined in this context`.

I realise I can do:

```
data class Outer(val x:Int, val predicate: Predicate<Int> = Predicate<Int> { it == x }) {
}
```

but I want my Inner to be Seralizable so it cannot be an anonymous class.

Comment: You do realise that `inner class` are like non-static inner classes in Java, and you do need an instance of `Outer` to create them, right?

Comment: @Sweeper Excellent question - and I found the answer.

Comment: Since `Inner` is in the constructor of `Outer` and this can be overriden, this is possible according to Outer: `val differentInner = Inner(); Outer(x, differentInner)`. The 2 solutions are: 1. remove `inner` or 2. remove `Inner` from the constructor.

Comment: @Sweeper - On your comment about infinite recursion on my wrong answer - that would be fun :)

Answer (score 2):

`inner class`es are like non-static inner classes in Java, and you need an instance of `Outer` to create them. However, when specifying the default values of the constructor parameters, the instance of `Outer` that you are creating (aka `this`) has not been created yet, so you cannot do `this.Inner()`.

For this scenario, you can remove `inner`, to make the `Inner` class more like a static inner class in Java. Add an `Int` constructor parameter to it so that you can pass the `x` from the outer to it:

```
data class Outer(val x: Int = 1, val predicate: Predicate<Int> = Inner(x)) {
    private class Inner(val x: Int) : Predicate<Int> {
        override fun test(t: Int): Boolean = x == t
    }
}
```

Comment: That is certainly an option but at a cost of an extra parameter which I'd rather avoid